# AnyDesk Can't Start as Root and I Can't Unlock Security Setting

Tags: anydesk

Please Help I can't Remote use AnyDesk and Anydesk on Ubuntu 20.04

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: As the message clearly states, you shouldn't be running Anydesk as root. Why are you doing that? If it doesn't run as normal (without `sudo`) then please edit your question and post the error messages.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. This worked for me.

1. open a terminal (ctrl+alt+T)
2. log in as root (sudo su + your root password)
3. type: anydesk --admin-settings

if you cant set your unattended password from here, try this...

echo  | anydesk --set-password

...also as root from the terminal.

Here's the source:

https://support.anydesk.com/knowledge/command-line-interface-for-linux#clientcommpara